# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at GraphQlElements

Tags: jss

I am Using Connected GraphQL query to fetch the data of the item.

It works fine in the GraphQL editor. But I created a component called `GraphQLDemo` and used the that query and fetched the data and delpoyed the component to my local Sitecore instance, it gave me the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
   at GraphQLElements (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:35011:269)
   at c (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:14020:496)
   at Ga (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:14023:1)
   at a.render (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:14028:367)
   at a.read (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:14027:450)
   at renderToString (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:14039:82)
   at process (D:\Websites_New\sc910JSS.local\dist\ssr\server.bundle.js:22217:20)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My Query is:

```
query ConnectedDemoQuery($contextItem: String!) {
  contextItem: item(path: $contextItem) {
    id
    ...RecursiveItems
  }
}

fragment RecursiveItems on Item {
  ...ItemData
  children(requirePresentation: true) {
    url(options: {disableLanguageEmbedding: true})
    ...ItemData
    children(requirePresentation: true) {
      url(options: {disableLanguageEmbedding: true})
      ...ItemData
    }
  }
}

fragment ItemData on Item {
  id
  path
  name
  fields {
    PageTitle: value
    heading: value
  }
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: check the datasource value in connected mode.

Comment: I have added Datasource value to my component,But still showing same error.

Comment: The query looks weird,  PageTitle and Heading contain both the field value and are equal.. (you can also use name instead of value to get the field name)  But the error is in your JavaScript app. The GraphQL query works or at least do not throw an error if it works in the GraphQL editor with the same context.

Comment: My query is working fine in editor also it is giving correct result.my index.js file code is:

Comment: Use connected mode to run the GraphQL query at the client-side for easier debugging. Then the network tab of your browser dev tools will let you inspect what's going on. Or, you can enable Node debugging to diagnose SSR: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/ssr/configuring-and-debugging-ssr